# What's the most efficient way to handle a redirect of the home page?

Tags: redirect, reroute, htaccess

I dont't currently need a home page on the personal site I'm working on but I want to be able to keep the option open in the future. I currently have

```
{% redirect 'portfolio' %}
```

as the only code on the index page but Craft seems to take a while before it redirects to the portfolio page.

I tried a rewrite rule and while it worked it doesn't change the URL and I didn't see much difference in the time it took to load the page. In fact, it seemed to take longer on my local machine running MAMP Pro 3 then the redirect tag did.

I also looked into [Reroute plug-in by Trevor Davis](https://github.com/davist11/craft-reroute) which seemed to work about as well as the redirect tag, maybe slightly better.

Any thoughts as to which is a better approach and why a simple index page with a redirect tag on it would take so long to process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.htaccess should *always* be faster because it doesn't involve PHP or Craft at all.

But on top of that the {% redirect %} tag should be pretty darn quick.

Upon hitting it, Craft immediately calls Yii's [CHttpRequest->redirect()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L799), which sets the redirect header and terminates the current request.

Comment: Note: if you get in the situation of requires *many* redirects [this question may be useful](https://serverfault.com/questions/414225/apache-what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-thousands-of-permanent-redirects). I only mention this because I stumbled on this page while looking for "efficient apache redirects".